# Reading some data from string C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am reading some .txt files that have data on it. My "strategy" for doing this is just reading the file line by line. I have no problems doing this task, however, at some point I have a string with different data (separated by spaces). I just want to read some data, because I do not need all the data. I used sscanf from string.h for doing this, this is an example of what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "1 189.37823  62.18428  2.486 25.33 -21.73 -21.68 -22.01 10.12 10.13 10.11 10.08  9.95  9.89  9.91 7    8.7    0 -42.85";

    int id, xid;
    double z, r, d, sfr, tmp;
    sscanf(str, "%d %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",
           &id, &z, &r, &d, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp,
           &tmp, &sfr, &xid, &tmp);

    printf("id = %d, z = %lf, r = %lf, d = %lf, sfr = %lf, xid = %d\n", id, z, r, d, sfr, xid);
}
```

However, my solution is quite inelegant, I am just "reading" all the data, and for the data I don't need I use a temporal variable. Is there a more correct (and perhaps more efficient) way for doing this?

Comment: amongst other details, the returned value (not the parameter values) from sscanf() needs to be checked to assure all the inputs were successfully read/converted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%*f` to read real value and drop it.

```
sscanf(str, "%d %lf %lf %lf %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %lf %lf %*f",
          &id, &z, &r, &d, &sfr, &xid);
```

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid right now. Thanks for the answer! pretty simple way to fix what I wanted :)

Answer (score -1):

If we may, just ignore the last one, because it's not necessary,
then we have:

```
sscanf( str, "%d %lf %lf %lf, &id, &z, &r, &d);
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) // easy to control skip how many number
    sscanf( str, "%lf, &tmp);
sscanf( str, "%lf %lf", &sfr, &xid);
```

Comment: no, because the 'str' address passed to sscanf) has not been updated.  While this technique might work for reading a file or reading stdin, where the location/file pointer gets updated, for data in memory 'str' always points to the same location so every sscanf() will be re-reading the same data